# How to find MongoDB records that have matching values in an array

Tags: mongodb

I am tracking user IP's by adding them to an array on the user document like so:

```
{
  "_id": "LafnHzmQL6rBmXNxJ",
  "name": "someuser",
  "displayName": "SomeUser",
  "knownIPs": ["1.1.1.1", "2.2.2.2", "3.3.3.3"]
}
```

How can I find any documents where **any** 1 of the `knownIPs` match **any** 1 of the `knownIPs` in another (without specifying a particular value) regardless of what the actual IP is.

The goal is to identify people who are using multiple accounts so they can be flagged programmatically for further inspection. I have over 40,000 users, will this be too intensive of an aggregation?

Comment: What command you have tried so far?

Comment: Use $in https://docs.mongodb.org/master/reference/operator/query/in/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following aggregation pipeline:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$unwind": "$knownIPs" },
    {
        "$group": {
            // Group by the IP address
            "_id": "$knownIPs",

            // Count number of matching docs for the group
            "count": { "$sum":  1 },

            // Save the _id for matching docs
            "docs": { "$push": "$_id" }
        }
    },
    {
        "$match": {
            "count": { "$gt": 1 }
        }
    }
])
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use $unwind function on the array of knownIPs. so that it will give you three child object from parent object.

For example:

```
db.document_name.aggregate( [ { $unwind : "$knownIPs" } ] ) gives you

{
  "_id": "LafnHzmQL6rBmXNxJ",
  "name": "someuser",
  "displayName": "SomeUser",
  "knownIPs": "1.1.1.1"
}

{
  "_id": "LafnHzmQL6rBmXNxJ",
  "name": "someuser",
  "displayName": "SomeUser",
  "knownIPs": "2.2.2.2"
}

{
  "_id": "LafnHzmQL6rBmXNxJ",
  "name": "someuser",
  "displayName": "SomeUser",
  "knownIPs": "3.3.3.3"
}
```

After unwind operation, perform GroupBy operation on all the objects generated from unwind operation. So it will give the number of users who have same Ip.